# Calculate intersection between points and polygon whose coordinates are lat & longitude in postgis

Tags: postgis

I have a table called as events. events has a column of point datatype. (x,y) = (latitude,longitude) for the point.
Now, I have an another set of points whose latitude and longitude are known. Now, I want to form a polygon of these points and then want to know how many event points are present in this polygon.
I am not able to formulate the query.

I tried using

```
ST_AsText(ST_PointOnSurface('POLYGON((0 0, 0 5, 5 5, 5 0, 0 0))'::geometry));
```

But couldn't find the answer.

Comment: You'll make it easier for us to help you if you add some sample data. FWIW I think your query will involve st_geomfromtext for your polygons and st_contains. Try something with those, and if you're still stuck post your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to incorporate [ST_Point](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html) to create a geometry from your LatLong and [ST_Intersects](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html) to determine which points intersect the polygon.